# Store user name and password with neo4j connection string

Tags: neo4j

What is the format (if any) for adding user name and password to neo4j v4 connection strings? So far, I've seen just examples like `bolt://localhost:7010` with authentication being added as extra arguments to the connection calls.

Here's why I'm asking:

I have an ASP.NET app which connects to both MS SQL and neo4j DBs. For MS SQL, I can add the connection string to the `/configuration/connectionStrings` in web.config formatted like this

`<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;UID=user;PWD=pwd" />`

or

`<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDB;UID=user;PWD=pwd" />`

It contains host name, instance name or port name, plus the credentials. I can then encrypt the connectionStrings part of web.config using standard IIS tools.

For ease of management, I'd like to reuse it for neo4j connection strings as well. I could store the string in MSSQL-like format
 `<add name="MyNeo4jDB" connectionString="Data Source=.,7010;UID=user;PWD=pwd" />`
but I don't want to invent my own format.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to stick to https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/client-applications/#driver-configuration-examples, I think.

Comment: Also passing user info in the URI has been deprecated, you should really not do that : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.1

Comment: @fbiville Thanks, so it looks like neo4j does not support connection strings which include user name and password. This is different from SQL Server and I'll workaround it.